# meaning of the adverb "whence"

Tags: adverbs

What does "whence" mean in the following?

They returned whence they had come.

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary defines it as "from where":

But Oxford Dictionary Online lists as one of its senses "to the place from which."

If we follow the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary's definition, does the sentence mean "They returned from where they had come"? Is that a correct definition?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whence?q=whence

Comment: I think that someone who has been a member of ELL for over four years should show some effort and share their research, looking up the word in a dictionary is the first step. If you don't say that you looked up "whence" users are going to presume you need a dictionary definition. Explaining why you are still confused despite having looked up the word in two or three online dictionaries makes the question more challenging, more interesting for users to answer, and more useful for future visitors.

Comment: *That which was raised up from the dust has [**returned from whence it came.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22returned+from+whence+it+came%22)

Comment: Why do you think **from where** and **to the place from which** resolve to different meanings?  It's just a difference of direction, but the place is the same place, the starting or originating point.

Answer (score 4):

**whence** is [moribund verging on archaic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they%20returned%20whence%20they%20came&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20returned%20whence%20they%20came%3B%2Cc0) when referring to the origin as a *destination* :

> They returned whence they came.

**whence** as referring to the original place, the place of starting out (and figuratively to the source of something) is not in colloquial register.

Comment: Thank you, I'd like to know whether "They returned whence they came" means the same as "They returned to the place from which they came." I'm a bit puzzled about why you said "It's just a difference of direction."

Comment: @Apollyon Metaphorically, *from where* means that a journey took place starting at point A and ending at point B (going away).. *To the place from which* would mean, having gone from point A to point B, there is now a return to point A again (going toward). But none of that has any bearing on **whence**, which just means the starting point. And since "returned" is used in your example sentence anyway, they are going back to the starting point regardless.

Comment: @Apollyon. Yes, it does. They made a U-turn.