# position of "from"

Tags: prepositions, word-order, formality

Is there any difference between the following sentences?

> They returned where they had come **from**.
>
> They returned **from** where they had come.

Comment: No difference in meaning whatsoever. This question, I presume, is connected to your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167608/meaning-of-the-adverb-whence) about “whence”, isn't it?

Comment: The latter might be perceived as slightly more formal-sounding due to pied-piping of the preposition.